# how to submit form data with jquery adding id with value

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function () {    
          // var action = $(this).attr("action",'order_confirmation.php');
          var $inputs = $('#order :input');
          var data = "details=order" + $.map($("input:radio:checked"), function(elem, idx) 
          {
            return "&"+$(elem).attr("name")+"="+ $(elem).val()+ "_" +$(elem).attr("id");
          }).join('');
    });
});
```

I have use the jquery with form submitting and i have changed the checked radio buttion value with id and i am not able to post a form jquery

Comment: i need to get the posted result on php page

Comment: Can you also post your html code? It's not clear how you are doing?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You want to use AJAX to send js parameters in a php file?

Comment: yes, i need only send data to php file and retrieve what i send the details=order&test=test ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX method in jQuery

```
$.ajax({cache:false,dataType:'html',
        crossDomain:true,type:'GET', // You can use POST or GET
        url:'pathPhpFile',
        data : {data,yourData,data2:yourData2}, // data send with GET method
        success:function(html){
            alert(html);  // Result of PHP               
        },
        error:function(j,t,e){
        console.log('bug');
        }
});
```

**PHP**

```
$data = $_GET["data"];
$data2 = $_GET["data2"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a form via JQuery like this:

```
 $('#form-id').submit(function() {
      var user_id = "id_" + $("#input-id").val();
      $("#input-id").val(user_id);
      return true;
 });
```

See JQuery **[Submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)** documentation.

Comment: i am getting only form post value for example user_id=20 and i need this result user_id=id_20

Comment: posted value display in php page

Comment: Can you post the html?

Answer (score 0):

**Script**

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $inputs = $('#order :input');
    var data = "details=order" + $.map($("input:radio:checked"), function(elem, idx) {
        return "&"+$(elem).attr("name")+"="+$(elem).attr("id")+ "_" +;$(elem).val()
    }).join('');
    $.post($('form').attr('action'), data, function(res) {

    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$_POST['element_name_you_want_to_retrieve'];
```

**update**

```
var data = "details=order" + $.map($("input:radio:checked"), function(elem, idx) {
            return "&"+$(elem).attr("name")+"="+ $(elem).attr("id")+ "_" +;$(elem).val()
        }).join('');
```

Comment: can you please explain this $_POST['element_name_you_want_to_retrieve'];

Comment: the html form element name that you want to retrieve in your `php` script.

Comment: suppose you the form input like this
`<input type="text" name="username" value="myname" />`

then you can get the value of this input in your php script as like this.

`$_POST['username'] // gives the value i.e. myname`

Comment: form direct to the test.php and print what i have send for example test=test_50&test2=test2_4  with out ajax

Comment: Then what you want now

Comment: i need submit this data to php page and page will display like this data=details_20&test=test3_20

Comment: form posting is not working i got error like Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Comment: i need to display the posted value to php page